# Passing double array from Python to Javascript for updating a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, multidimensional-array, data-transfer

I'm scraping the availability of courses off my school's webpage using Python and store that data into a double array (for example: [ ["MAC 2311", "1"], ["COP 2210", "0"], ...] ), where 1 represents available and 0 represents not available. This scraper runs every 5 minutes.

I created a webpage with buttons that light up either green or red depending on the availability of the course and I want to use this double array to update that status. But I don't know how to pass the double array from Python to Javascript to do so.

```
import scraperSummer

def main():
   classObject = scraperSummer.TestFIUSearchPage()

   # if semester is available, then availability_list gets a
   # double array containing the status of the courses
   if classObject.summerSemester:
      availability_list = classObject.scrape()
   else:
      print ("Semester is not available")

main()
```

Comment: You can create a template variable and then in HTML, do `var jsVar = JSON.parse("{{djangoVar | escapejs}}")`

Comment: How do I create a template variable? @Rajesh